# how can i check if a php associative array's key is equal to a defined variable from phptal condition?

Tags: view, conditional-statements, template-tal, phptal

i've this problem my phptal view has a variable called data which is an associative array.

Let's suppose that i've those Keys M01 M02 and M03 **not in a particular order**, i've to print to the user view all the data not referred by key M02.

How can i do this?
Thanks in advance

Marco

**UPDATE: I forgot to say that i cannot edit the code which calls the view.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If order is important, use second array with ordered keys to print:

```
<div tal:repeat="key php:array('M01','M03')" tal:content="array/$key"/>
```

Otherwise you can just add a condition:

```
<div tal:repeat="data array">
    <tal:block tal:condition="php:repeat.data.key != 'M02'" tal:content="data"/>
</div>
```

Comment: @Kornel the latest phptal supports `EQ`or`NE` instead of `==`or`!=`;)